# Transforming PointCloud2

Tags: pointcloud, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if somebody knows what is the substitute for the function of transformPointCloud() for PointCloud2 data type as in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/71/how-to-transform-pointcloud2-with-tf). I've tried to go to the [link](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html) provided but it seems to be deprecated(I guess) as I cannot find in my autocompletion mode.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12890/transforming-pointcloud2/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You had found the correct answer: `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud()` is the function to call.

The generated documentation link may have changed. Try looking for it starting with the  [main `pcl_ros` API page](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/pcl_ros/html/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-05**:
Last time, i just included "#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>", but this one doesn't suffice.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-05**:
I see, thanks a lot for the clarification.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-05**:
I never heard it was deprecated. For Fuerte, the big PCL library will become a rosdep, but pcl_ros still exists.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-05**:
Thanks a lot. That worked! By the way, why someone said that pcl_ros is deprecated already, but when I go to the API doc, it is still someone actively committing codes last few days?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-05**:
Did you #include <pcl_ros/transforms.h> ?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-05**:
Why can't I use it? I've already included pcl_ros in the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can transform using the tf2_sensor_msgs (both C++ and Python interface, since at least Indigo):

```
#include <tf2_sensor_msgs.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>

const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_in, cloud_out;
const geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transform;
// TODO load everything
tf2::doTransform (cloud_in, cloud_out, transform);
```

Or in Python:

```
from tf2_sensor_msgs.tf2_sensor_msgs import do_transform_cloud
cloud_out = do_transform_cloud(cloud_in, transform)
```

None of the codes was really tested, though I intend to use them tomorrow. If you test them and find a bug, please edit my answer. I really wonder why there aren't more tutorials for this kind of essential conversions.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueflame](https://answers.ros.org/users/26744/blueflame/) on 2017-10-02**:
What's the right data format for "transform" in python?

**Comment by [blueflame](https://answers.ros.org/users/26744/blueflame/) on 2017-10-02**:
Let me post my example code here in python:

`import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2`

`from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2`

`from tf2_sensor_msgs.tf2_sensor_msgs import do_transform_cloud`

`import tf2_ros`

**Comment by [blueflame](https://answers.ros.org/users/26744/blueflame/) on 2017-10-02**:
`tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()`

`tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tf_buffer)`

`transform = tf_buffer.lookup_transform("camera_link","map", rospy.Time())`

`pcd2_camera = do_transform_cloud(pcd2, transform)`

This help to trasform pointclouds2 from "map" link into camera_link

**Comment by [lr101095](https://answers.ros.org/users/34104/lr101095/) on 2018-05-16**:
@blueflame does your code actually work? because i tried to implement it but i get
`ImportError: No module named tf2_sensor_msgs.tf2_sensor_msgs`

Please advise

**Comment by [diogoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/30827/diogoa/) on 2018-08-27**:
Hi! Make sure you installed the tf2_sensor_msgs package for your ros distribution.

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2019-11-24**:
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-tf2-sensor-msgs

**Comment by [Vignesh_93](https://answers.ros.org/users/65377/vignesh_93/) on 2021-03-31**:
I have tested this part of the code and am facing some offset issues, meaning there is an increasing offset issue with it.
Let me explain it furthur, so I have the laser scan data in laser frame being plotted in the rviz and I then convert the same point cloud frame to odom frame and then plot the same in rviz. Initially there is an offset only in the z axis at the start position but as the robot moves the point cloud data keeps drifting away from the laser scan plot. Has anyone else faced this issue as well ?